# Getting SEVERE: null java.sql.SQLException: No data found error

Tags: java, sql, sqlexception

I am trying to store the DB value into two different array. if test_type is ”New”=> store first array, else=> second array. Am getting “SEVERE: null java.sql.SQLException: No data found error” while assign rs.getString value to variable\array. Could anyone help me to solve the issue? Am using MS access as DB

code:

```
try {   
   DatabaseConnectivity();      
   stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
   String select="Select * from (SELECT DISTINCT test_name,test_type FROM ScenarioTable)order by test_type ";                
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);  
   String colvalues;
   String print="null";
   int arycount=1;
   basicarray=new String [20][20];
   newarray=new String [20][20];                
   while (rs.next()) { 
     print=rs.getString(1);
     if (print.equals("New")) {
          for(int itration=1;itration<=2;itration++) {                               
             colvalues=rs.getString(itration);                                                        
             newarray[arycount][itration]=colvalues;
          } 
     } else {
         for(int itration=1;itration<=2;itration++) { 
            colvalues=rs.getString(itration);                                                        
            basicarray[arycount][itration]=colvalues;
         }
        arycount++;
    }
```

error:

```
Connection Successful
May 04, 2015 8:26:37 AM NewJFrame btn_refreshActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: No data found
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7145)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(JdbcOdbc.java:3914)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5697)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:353)
    at NewJFrame.btn_refreshActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:1140)
    at NewJFrame.access$1800(NewJFrame.java:47)
    at NewJFrame$21.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:734)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
```

Answer (score 1):

The same data should not be retrieved more than once from the result set.
Namely, because `rs.getString(1)` was executed twice, the exception was thrown.
Use another variable to keep the value of `rs.getString(1)`